# How to get height of a horizon chart of d3.js at a particular x co-ordinate value?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am trying to create a horizon chart using d3.js and http://kmandov.github.io/d3-horizon-chart/. However, I need to implement some additional functionalities, for which I need to know the height of the horizon chart on the given x co-ordinate location. I have looked over the source of d3-horizon-chart and I am unable to find out a way to accomplish this.
Is there any way to implement this functionality?